# Java ArrayList implementation

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I have been trying to compare definition of list and its implementation in Java as I feel there is a mismatch.

**Definition Of List DataStructure**:  a list or sequence is an abstract data type that implements an ordered collection of values, where the same value may occur more than once. [Taken from : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type) ]

Now an ordered collection maintains the order of insertion of elements.

Java Implementation of List -> [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) : As per this implementation, I have following points:

1. If I initialize an `ArrayList` of say size 5, then I cannot directly insert element at 5th position without inserting elements at position 1,2,3,4 because it will go against ordering principle. So Java gives exception here which I completely agree with.
2. `ArrayList` provides methods like "set(int index, E element)" and  "add(int index, E element)" using which we can replace elements in middle of list and can also insert new elements in middle of list. I do not understand this. It is going against principle of ordering as insertion order is not maintained.

I feel 1st and 2nd point are in conflict with each other and 2nd point is against principle of ordering or may be I am missing something.

Can somebody please explain where I am going wrong in my understanding of `List` here?

Comment: Check the formal definitions, as far as I understand ArrayList doesn't violate them.

Comment: Can you point me to some formal definition?

Comment: Check the wikipedia link. It's already there...

Comment: Please read post properly!! I have pasted deficinition from wikipedia only

Comment: I'm not referring to the definition that people may misinterpret... See the section `Abstract Definition`

Comment: @loki: I am pretty sure that your question is actually answered properly by stan0. You quote a section fro Wikipedia which mentions the ordering of lists and you interpret this as insertion ordering, which is not mentioned in the Wikipedia article at all. The operations in the Java list interface to replace, add and remove elemnts from a list from/at a specific index are all described in the Wikipedia paragraph "Characteristics".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The definition doesn't say anything about the size of the list or what happens when you add elements by index. It just says that the order of elements doesn't change "suddenly".

   This is the contrast to "set" types where the order of elements can change by adding new elements. If you insert an element at the 2nd position of a 5 element list, then the third element doesn't suddenly jump to the head of the list.
2. The definition also doesn't say which operations *must* have, only what it *might* have. For efficient operations on lists, it's useful to have a method to insert an element anywhere (withing the legal boundaries, of course) **and** to be able to replace an element without changing the indexes of existing elements.

   If the second operation was missing, replacing elements would take `add()` plus `remove()` which are both expensive operations, depending on the implementation.

   Also both operations clearly explain how they influence the ordering of the other element when they are applied. `set()` doesn't change the ordering of the other elements while `add()` increments the index of all elements after the insertion point.

Comment: When you say " order of elements doesn't change "suddenly". How do we measure sudden change ?

Comment: @loki: You can define that as: after an operation, the relative ordering of the elements which still stay in the list are the same.

Comment: Adding an element to a set can change the order of all elements. It might look as if someone had shuffled them. In a list, only elements after the insertion point changes and the relative order is always preserved: when I insert an element at position 2, element #2 is moved to position 3 but it's still after the first and before the old #3.

Answer (score 1):

`ordered collection of values` does not mean insertion-order. It means that there is a bunch of items placed somewhere one after another and you can access them in a sequence.

Having the ability to insert an item at a particular index gives you control over the order.

Comment: If i go by that defintion, then i should be allowed by ArrayList to insert elements at contiguos locations. So even if location 1 and 2 are empty, i should be allowed to insert at 3,4,5 as losg as it is contiguos. Isn't it?

Comment: Other languages (or even Java libraries implementing custom lists) may of course allow both lists with a non-contiguous index range or contiguous index ranges starting with an arbitrary index instead of 0. The API documentation for java.util.List does however imply that lists have a contiguous index range, which is numbered from 0 to length-1.

Answer (score 1):

An Arraylist has an order, thats all it means. If you insert a value somewhere it still has AN order, even if it seems silly. If you want to have a MEANINGFUL order, then you have to look at comparable interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList`, just like any `java.util.List`, maintains the element insertion order.

Let's say we have an empty `ArrayList`. We add A, then B, then C. The list will look as follows: `[A, B, C]`. Not `[C, A, B]` nor `[A, C, B]`. Now, if we insert D at index 1, the list will look as follows: `[A, D, B, C]`. Not `[A, B, C, D]` or anything else, which may be perfectly possible for other types of `Collection`s.

Java's `List` does not imply neither artificial element ordering, like `Sorted` collections do, nor random element ordering, like certain collections, such as `HashSet` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

You can add elements O to a list like `XXXXXXX`. With the added element you have `XXXXXXO`.

If you tried to add elements on a position that is greater than the size of the list you would have holes like `XXXXXX     O`.

The add(position, element) is used to add elements inside the list like add(2, O) -> `XXXOXX`

A List isn't a field of possible position like an array but a collection.

Comment: Don't you mean `put` in case of a position?

Comment: I agree with hole concept you talked about. How will you explain ordering?

Comment: put() is used by Maps and not by Collections.

You order by implementing the Interface Compareable<T> and defining a ordering value algorithm. Then you could order the list with Collections.sort(list)

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does not keep the order and has random get/set methods. This is correct.

I would say the wiki definition is just wrong, not completely correct, or does not apply to what Java understands under `List`, which is obviously a little less than `Ordered List`

If you want to have ordering on insert, Java SE API provides [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to which you have to provide a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) at creation time or have the element inserted implement the interface [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Otherwise, the elements are ordered using their natural ordering.

In my opinion Java's `ArrayList` is just a managed array, which is handy and fits for most use cases.